# Find $f(2z)$ given $f(z) = 10$ and $f(x) = \frac{a^x + a^{-x}}{a^x - a^{-x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to work out some basic algebra, the question is,

> If $$f(x) = \frac{a^x + a^{-x}}{a^x - a^{-x}}$$ and $f(z) = 10$ show what $f(2z)$ equals.

I have manipulated the function as far as $f(x) = \frac{1}{2a^x  -1}$.

What should I do next, solve for $z$ in terms of $b$?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is $$f(x)=\frac{a^{2x}+1}{a^{2x}-1}$$

I am not sure where you get your last expression. Anyway, solving $f(x)=10$

$$\frac{a^{2x}+1}{a^{2x}-1}=10$$

$$a^{2x}=\frac{11}{9}\tag{componendo and dividendo}$$

$$a^{4x}=\frac{121}{81}$$

$$f(2x)=\frac{202}{40}=\frac{101}{20}\tag{componendo and dividendo}$$

Comment: Thank you I see where I went wrong.

Comment: @user2352274 you're welcome. :) all of us makes arithmetic mistakes, be a little careful.